# asp.net displaying stored procedure results on HtmlTable from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

what is the best way to dynamically create a table from codebehind, where data for it is retrieved from a stored procedure (SQL 2008)??
And will it make difference if I use HtmlTable instead of asp.net Table?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are u going to make modification also in the HtmlTable/Asp.net Table ? I mean edit/delete functionality will be there? Are you going to display data in single page or using Paging?

Comment: Only displaying data, no edit/delete etc and without paging, as there is only few data to display on every table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned you wanted it to be easy the GridView is the way to go. Yes you can use the html table but it will be more work.

I wanted to mention another approach. You could make an html table with a repeater as well. I found a sample for you here:

[ASP.NET Web Form Repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp)

If you scroll down a bit you will see an example of a table.

This is also simple as you can bind to the repeater as Icarus showed but you also get a little bit more straightforward control of the html.

Comment: Thanks, i've created a simple html table although without a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `GridView`with`SqlDataSource`, you realize productivity gains, you have created infrastructure for this.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand.aspx

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply! Since I only have to display a small amount of data (<10), I'd like to use something more simple and light-weighted.

Comment: I recommend you to use GridView and SqlDataSource because development with Htmltable it's laborious,, maybe that you develop in java so you want make the same work, but i suggest you tu use GridView, because in the future you can develop easily Update ou Delete Or edit, and if you have questions, you will find alwas person who can bring answer

Comment: @Candie It's matter of 10 odd records. Why `GridView`? Why not `Repeater`? or Why not a simple Iteration at `Code Behind` using `<table>`

Comment: Yes also you can try with repetarer, why not table , because if you want upgrade you can with asp.net control easily

Answer (score 0):

The best way is simply to bind the results of the proc to a GridView (I am assuming you are using web forms). Something like this

```
var results = dataRep.GetData();
Grid.DataSource=results;
Grid.DataBind();
```

It will generate all the columns automatically by default.

If you need to control which columns are to be displayed from the results, you can set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false and manually define in the markup the columns you want. Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ...
<Columns>
 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ColumnNameFromResult" />
```

Comment: I'm using .net4 and c# and I really would like to use something more simple then GridView, as I have only small amount of data to display. Or will it be too much effort to use HtmlTable?

Comment: Gridview will render as a regular HTML table. You can definitely use HTMLTable if you want, but then you need to write the code to loop through the rows and columns of the result set and build every cell. If this is as simple as you say, I wouldn't worry about using a GridView. If you are concerned about the size of the page due to ViewState, you can always disable ViewState on the GridView alone or at the page level.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have decided to go with a simple html table, as the premise of the problem has changed a bit. Now, i have to retrieve a data from a single stored procedure and display all the result sets (in this case 3) in separate tables.